# How to I stage a GCP/Apache Beam Dataflow template?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Ok I have to be missing something here. What do i need to stage a pipeline as a template? When I try to stage my template with via [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#creating-and-staging-templates), it runs the module but doesn't stage anything., it appears to function as expected without errors, but I don't see any files actually get added to the bucket location listen in my --template_location. Should my python code be showing up there? I assume so right? I have made sure i have all the beam and google cloud SDKs installed, but maybe I'm missing something? What do you need to do to stage this dataflow template? Also can I manually just drop the file in a bucket and run it from there? The following is the template I am currently playing with:

```py
import json
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery import parse_table_schema_from_json

GC_PROJECT = 'my-proj'
BUCKET = 'test-bucket'
STAGING_BUCKET = '%s/test' % BUCKET
TEMP_BUCKET = '%s/test' % BUCKET
# RUNNER = 'DataflowRunner'
RUNNER = 'DirectRunner'

# pipeline_args = ['--save_main_session']
pipeline_args = []
pipeline_args.append('--project=%s' % GC_PROJECT)
pipeline_args.append('--runner=%s' % RUNNER)
pipeline_args.append('--staging_location=gs://%s' % STAGING_BUCKET)
pipeline_args.append('--temp_location=gs://%s' % TEMP_BUCKET)

BQ_DATASET = 'lake'
BQ_TABLE = 'whatever'

SCHEMA_OBJ = [
    {"name": "id", "type": "STRING", "description": ""},
    {"name": "value", "type": "STRING", "description": ""}
]


class ContactUploadOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--infile',
            type=str,
            help='path of input file',
            default='gs://%s/data_files/test.csv' % BUCKET)

def run(argv=None):
    print('running')
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_args))
    lines = (p
             | beam.Create([
                {"id": "some random name", "value": "i dont know"},
                {"id": "id2", "value": "whatever man"}]))

    schema_str = '{"fields": ' + json.dumps(SCHEMA_OBJ) + '}'
    schema = parse_table_schema_from_json(schema_str)
    output_destination = '%s.%s' % (BQ_DATASET, BQ_TABLE)
    (lines
        | 'Write lines to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            output_destination,
            schema=schema,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))

    p.run().wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(pipeline_args)
```

Also, if someone could link some sdk documentaion/resources that explain how/why the staging instructions above are supposed to work, that would be awesome!

Comment: this morning I am trying to reset my python environment and dependencies to try and fix this and then maybe trying to manually stage the template. And if that fails, I may try Java

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: @VikramShinde no errors, but i think it was just a dumb mistake on my part not passing my runtime args in correctly. So it was working but never considered my template_location that I was passing in via command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temp location is where the temporary files will be loaded while running the job. You have not mentioned the "template_location" where template will be created.

Please see link for [creating template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates)  and [running template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/running-templates)

Comment: ooohhh yeah i see what you're saying, yeah haha ok my runtime args were not being considerred which means the template_location never cot looked at and therefore never staged my template... ill give it a shot.

Comment: hello Vikram, when you get time, can u please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59894035/attribute-error-while-creating-custom-template-using-python-in-dataflow